# In which countries can a US citizen stay permanently (preferrably free)?

Tags: us-citizens

I'm referring to the ability to permanently reside in a country, without giving up my US citizenship and without having to pay any hefty fees. For instance, I'd be willing to pay a few thousand dollars, but I wouldn't be willing to pay eighty thousand dollars. My wife and I want to go live abroad for a while (possibly in each place for 6+ months), but we're trying to figure out in which countries we could easily do that.

Comment: Pay for what? For accomodation, food, going out? Taxes? Bribes?

Comment: There's a big difference between places you could 'permanently reside' in, and places you could 'work' in. Also, six months is, in many cases, not long enough to be considered 'permanent residence' anyway.

Comment: Some places offer Permanent Residency or Citizenship through investments and/or new businesses, is that the sort of thing you have in mind? (Typically the amounts involved are hundreds of thousands or low millions of dollars though)

Comment: Staying more than 90 days in the Schengen countries(most of Europe) without a work or student visa is going to be tough. And as far as I know it is cumulative for everything in the Schengen zone (meaning you can't stay 90 days in France followed directly by 90 days in Italy).

Comment: Welcome to Expats! I think we're going to be a great resource for you once you've narrowed down your search a bit. The best thing I can recommend is asking yourselves what kind of climate you could possibly thrive in (or not totally hate), what kind of culture you want to immerse into and narrow down your possibilities. Once you have, and you have a more specific question about relocating to one (or which out of several would be better given a specific criteria) we'd love to help and enjoy questions from your adventure.

Comment: I'm done here, forever. In fact, I'm done with StackExchange in general. When a question has an aggregate 4 up-votes, but is closed, something is broken. I don't need an explanation from anyone attempting to justify such stupidity.